# Seaborn lmplot: limits y-axis

Tags: python, seaborn, correlation

My question: help needed with configuring the y-axis in seaborn so that it will display a range from -1.0 to -0.8, then a gap, then from 0.8 to 1.0 (for displaying correlation coefficients in a lmplot)

```
ax_neg_1 = sns.lmplot('Aantal Sterkst Negatief', # Horizontal axis
       'Corr Sterkst Negatief', # Vertical axis
       data=df_PAR_metingen_half_1, # Data source
       fit_reg=False, # Don't fix a regression line
       hue="Sterkst Negatief", # Set color
       scatter_kws={"marker": "D", # Set marker style
                    "s": 100, 'alpha':0.3}, size=12) # S marker size, transparency & size

# Plot horizontal line
y=0
plt.axhline(y=y, c='red',linestyle='dashed',zorder=-1)

# Set title
plt.title('Correlations by chemical', fontweight='bold', fontsize=12)

# Set x-axis label
plt.xlabel('Count')

# Set y-axis label
plt.ylabel('Correlation Coefficient')

axes = ax_neg_1.axes
axes[0,0].set_ylim(-1, 1)
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you want to achieve without  a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A `lmplot` potentially returns several axes, plus you are explicitly not fitting a regression line, so are you sure that you want to use a lmplot? Toy data (e.g. using the tips dataset as in the doc `tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")`) and a mock-up of the desired output would be useful

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to use a lmplot to show the correlationcoefficients of different chemicals. It is just that I want to configure the y-axis so that it goes from -1.0 to -0.8 and then from 0.8 to 1.0, but with an 'empty' space in between, instead of just -1 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to test without the data, but this may help

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
axes[0,0].add_patch(Rectangle((-0.8, -1), 1.6, 1, color='white'))
```